# Counting Characters using Field Calculator - ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I am trying to use field calculator to populate a column based on the the number of characters in another column. I am using the Python Parser. I am not sure if the `.count()` function is appropriate in this case or if I am even using it right.

My pre-logic script is:

```
def reclass(f1):
     if f1.count() >= 4:
         return "Yes"
      else:
         return "No"


Label = reclass( !HUB! )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would make two changes:

1. Make sure your indentation is correct
2. Use `len()` to count the characters.  Make sure you are writing to a text field.

---

```
def reclass(f1):
     if len(f1) >= 4:
         return "Yes"
     else:
         return "No"

Label = reclass( !HUB! )
```

Answer (score 0):

Select by Attributes: `char_length(FIELD) >= number`

Field Calculate on the selected records

Comment: This Answer was flagged up as low quality due to its brevity.  I think you should edit it to explain that you are suggesting an alternative to using the Python Parser of the Field Calculator.